# Cant remove the div which added runt time by appending another div in MVC view

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am developing ASP.NET MVC application.

I am adding the Div Run time by click event on View using Jquery.

[image]

After adding div , I am trying to remove it... but It cant get removed.
I have put alert box on the click function of remove link but that also not working.

[image]

here is my Complete Code....

```
  <script type="text/javascript">


         $(document).ready(function () {

             $('.remove').click(function () {
                 alert("asd");
                 $(this).parent().parent().remove();


             });





        function getProductList(rIndex) {


            //alert("In Product list");
            var productList;
            var mainList;
            var productListArray = [];


            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Content("~/Product/GetProductList")',
                success: function(data) {


                    mainList = data;
                    var options = '';
                    temp = 0;
                    for (var index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {

                        productListArray[index] = data[index].Id;
                        options += '<option value="' + data[index].Id + '">' + data[index].Name + '</option>';
                    }
                    productList = options;

                    $("select#ddProductList_" + rIndex).html(productList);
                }
            });
        }





        $('#lnkAddProduct').click(function () {

            var rIndex = $("select.clsProductId").length;

           // $('#ProductList').append("<div><span style='font-size:12px;'><select class='clsProductId' id='ddProductList_" + rIndex + "' name='ProductId' style = 'font-size:12px;width:120px;margin-right:10px;margin-left:0px;' /></span><input type='text' id='SectionCode' style='width:10%; margin-right:30px;'></div>");
            $('#ProductList').append("<div><span style='font-size:12px;'><select class='clsProductId'  name='ProductId' id='ddProductList_" + rIndex + "'name='ProductId' style = 'font-size:12px;width:150px;margin-right:10px;margin-left:0px;' /></span><input type='text' id='SectionCode'  name='SectionCode' style='width:10%; margin-left:7px;'><input type='text' id='Size' name='Size' style='width:5%; margin-left:20px;'><input type='text' id='Length' name='Length' style='width:8%; margin-left:25px;'><input type='text' name='Thickness' id='Thickness' style='width:8%; margin-left:25px;'><input type='text' id='Weight' name='Weight' style='width:8%; margin-left:25px;'/><input type='text' id='Quantity'  name='Quantity' style='width:8%; margin-left:30px;'/><span style='margin-left:10px;padding-top:6px;'> <a href='#' style='font-size:14px;text-decoration:none;font-weight:bold;' id='lnkRemove' class='clsRemove remove'>X</a></span></div>");


            getProductList(rIndex);
        });

        getProductList(0);
    });

</script>
<html>
    <body>


           <div class="span11 " style="margin-bottom : 20px; ">
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="span1" style="margin-left:10px; width:100px;">
                        Section Name
                    </div>
                    <div class="span1"  style="margin-left:60px;width:120px;">
                       Section Code
                    </div>
                    <div class="span1"  style="margin-left:10px;width:60px;">
                        Size
                    </div>

                    <div class="span1"  style="margin-left:20px;width:80px;">
                       Length
                    </div>

                    <div class="span1"  style="margin-left:20px;width:80px;">
                     Thickness
                    </div>
                         <div class="span1"  style="margin-left:20px;width:90px;">
                     Avg. Weight
                    </div>
                    <div class="span1"  style="margin-left:35px;width:80px;">
                    Quantity
                    </div>
                </div>

             <div class="row-fluid" id="ProductList">


                        @*<input type="text" id="SectionName" style="width:10%; margin-right:40px;" />*@
                          <span style='font-size: 12px;margin-left:0px;'><select class='clsProductId span11'  id='ddProductList_0' name='ProductId' style='font-size:12px;width:150px;margin-right:3px;margin-left:0px;'>
                          <option selected="selected" value=""></option>
                          </select></span>



                        <input type="text" id="SectionCode" name="SectionCode" style="width:10%; margin-left:10px;" />


                       <input type="text" id="Size" name="Size" style="width:5%; margin-left:20px;" />



                        <input type="text" id="Length" name="Length" style="width:8%; margin-left:20px;" />


                        <input type="text" id="Thickness"  name="Thickness" style="width:8%; margin-left:20px;" />


                        <input type="text" id="Weight" name="Weight" style="width:8%; margin-left:20px;" />


                          <input type="text" id="Quantity" name="Quantity" style="width:8%; margin-left:30px;" />
                         @* <span style="margin-left:10px;padding-top:6px;"> <a href='#' style='font-size:14px;text-decoration:none;font-weight:bold;' id='lnkRemove' class='clsRemove remove'>X</a></span>

                         <a href='#' class='123'>X</a>

             <div class="span10" style="margin-left:0px;">
                   <a href="#" id="lnkAddProduct" style="font-size:14px;text-decoration:none;margin-right:10px;">Add Product</a>
                   <span id="LinkErrorMsg" class="field-validation-error"></span>
               </div>
           </div>
        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you need to delegate click event to closest static container. You should be able to find hundred (thousand?) duplicates of your question... Please read: https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: avoid that parent().parent() thing. it can easily went wrong as soon as you refactor or revise your UI. 1. Assign unique correct ID to your div. 2. Assign attribute to (x) which is ID of a div. 3.On click read attribute, find div and remove it.

Comment: Why to use delegate ? why its not working with my code, I have used same code in other modules in same project and it works fine..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try event delegation using [`.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) as your remove link is created runtime.

```
  $("#ProductList").on('click','.remove',function () {
      alert("asd");
      $(this).closest("div.row-fluid").remove(); // Avoid parent().parent() you can use .closest()
  });
```

## ref:

[`.closest() API docs`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Comment: It works but its removes all the rows.... If I have added 4 rows...and if I click on any remove button then it removes all the rows... and why its not working with my code, I have used same code in other projects...

Comment: @user1650894 Then you can change the selector like this `$(this).closest("div").remove()`. It should work now

Comment: Thanks a lot @Dhaval Marthak it works... but still I am wondering why my code didn't work...